# how to check current value on specific column (SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have one column (status), and the value will be waiting or on_process or finished. I will check if the velue is waiting, so I will get the max number (eg. waiting1, waiting2 --> so the max value is waiting2) then I will +1 it's max value, so the next status will be waiting3..

col_status
waiting1
waiting2
on_process
finished
.......

this is my code :

```
create PROCEDURE SP_queue
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NEWID VARCHAR(5);
    select @NEWID = max(convert(int,SUBSTRING(status, 8, 2)))  FROM myTable

SELECT 'Waiting'+convert(VARCHAR, @NEWID+1)
END
```

but if the column have another value (eg. on_process), I have error..
so anyone can help me how to check using if statement, if the value is waiting, so will be get the max value, and if the value is on_process / finished then do nothing..

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a where condition:

```
SELECT
  @NEWID = max(convert(int,SUBSTRING(status, 8, 2)))  
FROM myTable
WHERE [status]='Waiting'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change using strings to numbers. Set some special values for each state, ie. under 100 is someting other than waiting and from 100, 101, 102,... are waiting chains. It will be much easier and cleaner.